# Build a data internet usage app for windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Good day. I plan to build a wp 8.1 app to monitor my phone internet data usage and sms/call count. Is it possible to do it? As I heard it need to be done at kernel level. The app's idea is about same like Data Sense.

Best regards
Chong Han

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the currently available public APIs.

Comment: Thanks for replying, How if I want to read the USSD message from telco? Is it possible?

Comment: You cannot interact with calling or SMS in any way.